# python type hint not working while passing function() as argument

Tags: python, types, casting

In a iterative loop,I am trying to pass a cube() as one of the argument to a other function sum(), but getting error as in second iteration sum() value is returning NoneType datatype in place of int datatype even after type casting the function value.

code:

```
def main():
    print(sum1(cube, 1, 3))

def cube(x:int) ->int :
    return(x*x*x)

def sum1(f:int ,a,b) -> int :
    if a>b : 0
    else :
        f(a) + sum1(f, a+1, b)

if __name__ == '__main__' : main()
```

error i am getting is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Your `sum1` function does not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `return` statement in `sum1` function.

```
def sum1(f: int, a, b) -> int:
    if a > b:
        return 0
    else:
        return f(a) + sum1(f, a+1, b)
```

Comment: My bad :(, new to python.. but great thanks for the help Stas Deep.